# How do I set an OnTouchListener for a relativeLayout?

Tags: java, android, events

I want to capture two events from a relativeLayout. When the user clicks it and when the user releases his click (like mousedown/mouseup)

```
    rl.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            //
        }
    });
```

I tried setting up something like:

```
            if(event == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            }
```

But eclipse just throws an error about an incompatible operand type. Anyone who knows how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try...

```
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Works like charm! Thanks! Eclipse wants onTouch to return a boolean value also, should I just return false?

Comment: @soren.qvist: Return `true` if the action is one that your method has consumed (processed). Return `false` if it isn't an action that your method needs to process.

Comment: @soren.qvist: lol - there's so much in the docs though it's easy to miss stuff, I do it all the time myself.