# TouchEvent executing both if and else part

Tags: android, touch-event

In the code below the problem i m facing is that in onTouchListener method both if and else part is getting executed each time. Anyone have idea why is it happening like that? and aim of my project is on touch event on anywhere in on the webview the dock layout must appear on another touch it must disappear.Can anyone help regarding this?

Thanks in advance ..

```
     public class MathiasdockActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    RelativeLayout upperdock,parent;
    LinearLayout tocbottom,tocparent;
    boolean flag=true;
    WebView wv;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        parent=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl1);
        upperdock=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.upperdock);
        tocparent=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tocparent);
        tocbottom=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout3);
        upperdock.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.INVISIBLE);
        tocparent.setVisibility(LinearLayout.INVISIBLE);
        tocbottom.setVisibility(LinearLayout.INVISIBLE);
        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);  
        wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/hotspot/07-03.html");
        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);


        wv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    if(flag)
                    {
                            Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), Boolean.toString(flag) + "if", 1000);
                            toast1.show();
                            upperdock.bringToFront();
                            tocparent.bringToFront();
                            tocbottom.bringToFront();
                            upperdock.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);
                            tocparent.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
                            tocbottom.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
                            flag=false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                            Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), Boolean.toString(flag) + "else", 1000);
                            toast2.show();
                            wv.bringToFront();
                            upperdock.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.INVISIBLE);
                            tocparent.setVisibility(LinearLayout.INVISIBLE);
                            tocbottom.setVisibility(LinearLayout.INVISIBLE);
                            flag=true;  

                    }

                    return flag;
            }
        });
    }
   }
```

Comment: how you can to know it is executing both i fand else ......through debugging or through toast2 ?

Comment: @Dheeresh Singh through toast.

Comment: then you can try hotveryspicy answer and and find reason in Dhruv answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because `OnTouchListener` calls continuously, so you need to check that user touches first time by `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`

```
wv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if(event.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
                if(flag)
                {
                   Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), Boolean.toString(flag) + "if", 1000);
                   toast1.show();
                   upperdock.bringToFront();
                   tocparent.bringToFront();
                   tocbottom.bringToFront();
                   upperdock.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);
                   tocparent.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
                   tocbottom.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
                   flag=false;
                }
                else
                {
                   Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), Boolean.toString(flag) + "else", 1000);
                   toast2.show();
                   wv.bringToFront();
                   upperdock.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.INVISIBLE);
                   tocparent.setVisibility(LinearLayout.INVISIBLE);
                   tocbottom.setVisibility(LinearLayout.INVISIBLE);
                   flag=true;
                }
          }
              return flag;
        }
    });
```

Comment: i tried and its giving this error..( Incompatible operand types MotionEvent and int) any suggestions to clear it? i m new to android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559881/how-do-i-set-an-ontouchlistener-for-a-relativelayout through this link found the answer thanks for the help

Comment: I forgot to write *getAction()*. :)

Comment: Do you have any idea about toggling the appearance.. this answer helped me in solving the touch effect.. but how to toggle it? on alternate clicks it must toggle the appearance

Answer (score 1):

It only looks like both are being executed at the same time. In reality, they are executed separately, but **because the touch event is being fired so rapidly, it appears that they're both executed at the same time**. What you should be doing is detecting the type of the motion event first e.g., `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` or something. Otherwise, all motion events are handled by your listener code.

Of course the reason both `if` and `else` are called in your code is because you're setting the flag to true and false in each statement, so that the execution of the statements alternates.

Answer (score 1):

There are many action for touch event so please use it with if condition.

```
1.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN
2.MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE
3.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
.
.
.
etc
```

**and always `return false;`**

**Update**

```
if(event.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
{
  //when you touch on screen
}
else if(event.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
{
    //when you move your finger on screen
}
else if(event.getAction()== MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
{
  //when you release your finger from screen
}
```

Comment: i tried and its giving this error..( Incompatible operand types MotionEvent and int) any suggestions to clear it? i m new to android –

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559881/how-do-i-set-an-ontouchlistener-for-a-relativelayout through this link found the answer thanks for the help –

Comment: Still how to toggle the appearance of dock? Toggling is the problem

Comment: what your criteria and what you want on that condition??

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11912/discussion-between-droids-and-capdroid)

Comment: first touch it must make dock visible.. second click it must be invisible.. this is the criteria.. it must go on like this.