# Diasbling onTouchListener at some of the hotspots of html page

Tags: javascript, android, touch-event

In my project i have a `WebView` which displays a html page. In that html page using javascript have made hotspots so that on click to the hotspot the notification pops out.In my native code have implemented `onTouchListener` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811131/touchevent-executing-both-if-and-else-part) .Now what i actually need is, the `OnTouchListener` must not work or Should not take touch event on the hotspots.

Can anyone help me regarding this?

Comment: are you asking about JavaScript or Java?

Comment: also, what does your `onTouchListener` do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Many tries and cracking head finally found answer for the question.

Solution Lies Calling the function OntouchListener from `HTML` and it cannot be done through 
`Android`.

Thanks for the Help

Answer (score 1):

Now, I may have this backwards... but from your question it sounds like you **do not** want `onTouchListener` to take effect when hotspots are touched... only when areas outside the hotspots are touched.  If the opposite is true, just invert the condition below.

OK.  When a touch occurs, your `onTouchListener` is passed an event object that contains the details of the touch... in particular `clientX` and `clientY`, which represent the coordinates of the touch itself.

In this listener, you would only execute the desired code if the touch coordinates above do not lie in your hotspots.  If it were me, I would model each hotspot as a square with `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, and `y2` representing the coordinates of the corners.  Then the listener loops over the hotspots checking that (`clientX` is between `x1` and `x2` AND that `clientY` is between `y1` and `y2`).  If at any point in the loop this condition is true, your touch occurred inside a hotspot, so your listener should return false or otherwise exit without executing your special code.

**Edit**: I think I've misunderstood your question.  Perhaps you aren't asking about JavaScript at all...

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I asked this Question in the context of `Android` which include `HTML` Pages Having `Javascript`. What You suggested can be done in `Android` too.. But the problem is I have n number of `HTML` Pages where hotspot position differs.. Hope You Understood my problem...Do share if you have any idea in if we can attain this in `HTML` or `Javascript` too .. I mean a Generalized Result. Thanks for the Help

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the `onTouchListener` on Android-side at all? If not, just do not implement it, and all touch events will go to the WebView and finally to your web-page.